# Adding a `-` between word, will the word still have same meaning?

Tags: american-english, hyphens

Adding a `-` between word, will the word still have same meaning?

**Example**

```
re-open or reopen
re-install or reinstall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these two cases, yes. Most people leave out the hyphen.

But there are other cases where the words *do* have a different meaning: recover (get well after an illness) and re-cover (put another cover on, or replace the existing one), and resign (when you finish your employment with a company) and re-sign (sign again). The last two might occur in the same context.

Comment: so it should be `re-open` and `re-install` ?